# Do I need to update Unity components alongside unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, updates

I want to update from unity 2017 to 2018 and I need to know, after starting the installer is it ok if I installed just unity or I need to download everything else again like Android build support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. When updating Unity, you have to update each platform you use.You do this because each platform contains asset, dll and default files like Android Manifest. The dlls references updated Unity dll. Without updating, I am not even sure that Unity will even detect or list the platform. Even if it is listed without updating, expect some issues since some classes may be deprecated and removed or some assets may not be available.

It's true that Unity allows you to select which platform support to install but this is meant to reduce the amount of time it takes to install Unity. *It's not made so that you can update some and ignore some*. Let's just say that you only need Windows build, it's made so that you can install Unity and the Windows support without having to install other platforms which takes some time to download then install.

**NOTE:**

*When you run the Unity installer and and point to it to the old Unity path, the first thing it will do is uninstall the old Unity. This includes removing platform support files.*